# toggleClass() not working

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I'm having a strange problem, I tried to use toggleclass(), when I put it in the editor doesn't work (the rest of the js runs correctly, so I know the file is well linked) but when I try in web inspector it works perfectly any ideas?

```
var main=function(event){
    $('#lucas').click(function(event){
        $('#lucas').toggleClass('perfil2');
    });
};


$(document).ready(main);
```

I know I should probably use `this` instead of the second selector for the id right? (still doesn't make a difference, still woulnd't work)

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Is the element with the id `lucas` added dynamically?

Comment: Is `$('#lucas')` an element asynchronous loaded? Note that the toggle class only works after click in #lucas

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` and event delegation:

```
$(function(){
      $('body').on('click','#lucas',function(event){
            $(this).toggleClass('perfil2');
        });
})
```

note: your id needs to be unique

Comment: *I know I should probably use `this` instead of the second selector for the id right? (still doesn't make a difference, still woulnd't work)*

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#lucas').click(function(){ 
        $('#lucas').toggleClass('perfil2'); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It works well for me in fiddle.

```
var main=function(event){
$('#lucas').click(function(event){
    $('#lucas').toggleClass('perfil2');
});};
$(document).ready(main);
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jrp9pcx/)